# what is the difference between ArrayList<Integer> and ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>?

Tags: java, generics, collections

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
al.add(new ArrayList());
```

when i try to add ArrayList in the above code it is not possible, but when i use the below code it is possible.Can i know why

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> al1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>
al1.add(new ArrayList());
```

Comment: That is the difference, if you understand what `List` is, you can understand better what a list of list (`List<List<>>`) could be. Maybe think of - "You have a deck of cards, and then you have another deck of such decks."

Answer (score 3):

In the first snippet `al` is an ArrayList of Integers - so you can't add an ArrayList to it as an element.

In the second snippet `al1` is an ArrayList of ArrayLists of Integers, so an ArrayList is a valid element to add to it.